# RegEx to find if a given string starts with a specific string with C#

Tags: c#, regex

i have a string of html:

```
 "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ......"
```

or

```
"<body> ..........</body>"
```

I want to check if my string starts with `"<!DOCTYPE"`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`(?=^<!DOCTYPE).*`](http://regex101.com/r/cT1uV6/2)

Comment: @Avinash Why would you want to match the whole document (`.*`), if you only try to verify the start of the string?

Comment: RegEx and HTML... [you should think again about that approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1336590).

Comment: it matches that particular line only.

Comment: Thanks guys. i have to think it different.StartsWith is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the problem you describe a simple string StartsWith should do the trick
http://www.dotnetperls.com/startswith

Answer (score 3):

Just use .StartsWith against your string object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx